# Compare strings bwlow API 18

Tags: java, android, string-comparison

I searched and got clear that `==` is not used to compare the content of string variables but `equals()`.

However, AS reports that `equals()` is only available on API 19 (Android 4.4) and up and I targetted API 18 (my only phone is Android 4.3)

So right now, I'm doing `if (var1.contains(var2))` or `if (array[i].contains(var))` to compare strings and it works but it doesn't seem correct to me.

What would be the correct way to achieve this on API < 19?

Thanks.

Edit: for clarification (I don't know how to put inline images)

[With `==`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PecWc.png)

[With `equals()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfRmP.png)

Comparison fails with `equals()`.

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that `string1.equals(string2)` is not available.

Comment: It works also on Android 2.2 (Froyo). I mean... it works on **all** Android versions: it's Java.

Comment: It doesn't display any error, just fails the comparison even if the strings are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `equals` function of the [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class was added in Java JDK 1.0.

This version was released on January 23, 1996. It was called 'Oak' back then, so technically it predates even Java itself. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#JDK_1.0)).

In contrast, Android API 1 was [released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_1.0_.28API_1.29) on September 23, 2008. At this time it would be made with Java JDK 1.5 (latest version was Java SE 5 Update 16).

So in conclusion, `equals` *is* available on API level 18, there must be some other error.

---

After seeing the posted code, you are using `Objects.equals()`, which is a utility method that checks equals() in a null-safe manner.
In many cases, like yours, you don't need the extra null check because you know at least one of the objects is not null and you can just call equals directly:

```
if("una".equals(hourNames[realHour]))
```

Your hourNames array will probably not contain null elements so you should turn it around to the more readable order:

```
if(hourNames[realHour].equals("una"))
```

Comment: Right, thats what i did. I just wanted to be sure it was the right way. Thanks for the clarification about the null verification.

Answer (score 0):

use `hourNames[realHour].equals("una")`

yeah, that is a bug on android studio (or maybe from intellij idea).

Comment: What is a bug??

Answer (score 0):

Since `if (var1.contains(var2))` works for you why don't you post the exact strings ? In case you don't have debug capability, I would suggest using these to debug the point in difference in the strings:-

```
boolean    contentEquals(CharSequence cs)
public int compareTo(String anotherString)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Also you could use the simulator env and run this small test:-

```
String s1 = "Test";
String s2 = "Test";
if (s1.equals(s2))
    System.out.println("Equal");
else
    System.out.println("Not Equal");
```